# Covariance between $X$ and a non-decreasing function of $X$

Tags: covariance

During my stats class, the teacher mentionned the following property of univariate covariance. I was not able to figure out how to derive it, neither find other posts talking about it.

Suppose $X$ is a real random variable and let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a non-decreasing function. Further assume that $\mathbb{E}[X^2]$ and $\mathbb{E}[g^2(X)]$ are both finite. Then, $\mathbb{C}\mathrm{ov}(X, g(x)) \geq 0$.

I don't see where that property comes from. Any hint or help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: The inequality was indeed in the wrong direction. That was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Are you sure the inequality is correct? e.g. try $g(X)=X$

Comment: The covariance is proportional to the slope of the least-squares line.  Could that line possibly have a negative slope?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume wlog that $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$, then
$$\text{cov}(X,g(X))=\int xg(x)\,\text{d}P(x)=\int \underbrace{x[\overbrace{g(x)-g(0)}^{\ge 0\text{ when }x\ge 0\\\quad\  \text{and}\\\le 0\text{ when }x\le 0}]}_{\ge 0\text{ everywhere}}\,\text{d}P(x)+
\underbrace{\int xg(0)\,\text{d}P(x)}_{\text{equal to }0}\ge 0$$
Actually, the assumption $\mathbb{E}[X]=0$ is unnecessary as
\begin{align}\text{cov}(X,g(X))&=\int \{x-\mathbb{E}[X]\}\{g(x)-\mathbb E[g(X)]\}\,\text{d}P(x)\\&=\int \{x-\mathbb{E}[X]\}g(x)\,\text{d}P(x)-\mathbb E[g(X)]\times 0\\
&=\int \{x-\mathbb{E}[X]\}g(x)\,\text{d}P(x)\\
&=\int \underbrace{\{x-\mathbb{E}[X]\}\{g(x)-g(\mathbb E[X])\}}_{\ge 0}\,\text{d}P(x)\\
&\qquad+
\underbrace{\int \{x-\mathbb{E}[X]\}g(\mathbb E[X])\,\text{d}P(x)}_{\text{equal to }0}\ge 0\end{align}

Comment: Quick follow-up: the "trick" to define $\tilde{g}(x) := g(x) - g(0)$ is to make sure that $\forall x \leq 0$, $\tilde{g}(x) \leq 0$ and $\forall x > 0$, $\tilde{g}(x) \geq 0$ right ?

Comment: Isn't a term missing in the second part ? I would say that $cov(X, g(X)) = \int \{x - \mathbb{E}[X]\} \{g(x) - \mathbb{E}[g(X)]\}dP(x)$

Comment: In the first line of the answer, should $g(x)-g(0)$ not be $\leqslant 0$ instead of $\geqslant 0$ for $x\leqslant 0$? Maybe a little typo here.